# Azure Automation Runbook ADAL SQL support

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, automation, runbook

I am attempting to use an Azure Automation Runbook to run a query against an Azure SQL database using Azure AD credentials:

```bsh
$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'SqlAdminUser'
$Username = $cred.UserName
$Password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$Server = 'server.database.windows.net'
$Port = 1433
$cxnString = "Server=tcp:$Server,$Port;Database=$Database;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"

$cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
$cxn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$cxn.Close()
```

and I get the following error:

> Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.

So it seems like Azure Automation doesn't have the [ADAL SQL library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742) installed?  Is there any easy way to work around this (and still use an Azure AD account to connect)?

I used [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-use-a-SQL-Command-be77f9d2#content) example as a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created hybrid workers which allowed me to install the latest version of the [ADAL SQL library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48742), which supports Azure AD authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching username and password from $SqlCredential but you stored credentials in $cred variable. These variables need to be same. Also make sure an automation credential object is created in azure automation account with same name as 'SqlAdminUser'

Comment: good catch, that was a typo (which is now fixed), but has no relation to the error message I referenced